# Convergence in probability of subsequence of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

**Problem statement:** Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables. If

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}X_n \overset{Pr}\rightarrow  Z,$

and for a random subsequence $(X_{2k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$,

$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}X_{2k} \overset{Pr}\rightarrow Y,$

prove

$P(Z=Y)=1.$

**Attempt:** this seems to follow from results in real-analysis for convergence of a subsequence. But I am wondering how to define that sequence so that it matches the condition for convergence in probability.

Comment: $(X_{2k})$ converges in probability to both $Z$ and $Y$ which implies $Z=Y$ a.s..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|Y-Z|\leq |Y-X_{2n}|+|X_{2n}-Z|$ we have for any $\epsilon>0$ that

\begin{align}P(|Y-Z|>\epsilon)&\leq P(|Y-X_{2n}|+|X_{2n}-Z|>\epsilon)\\&\leq P\left(|Y-X_{2n}|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)+ P\left(|X_{2n}-Z|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)
\end{align}

which by hypothesis tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. But as everything in the left hand side is fixed, it must then be $P(|Y-Z|>\epsilon)=0$.  As $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $$P(|Y-Z|>0)= P\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\left\{|Y-Z|>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right)\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}P\left(|Y-Z|>\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$$
hence $P(Y=Z)=1$.

We are of course, using the fact that if a sequence converges in probability to $Y$ then every subsequence also converges in probability to $Y$ which DOES NOT imply that the limit is unique in probability and this is what you want to prove.

Comment: Thanks. It does not change the proof, but shouldn't the absolute values with $Z$ in them have $X_n$ instead of $X_{2n}$?

Comment: @k278 The $X_{2n}$ appears in the first step after inserting it like so: $$|Y-Z|=|Y-X_{2n}+X_{2n}-Z|$$ and using the triangle inequality. If you cared to have an $X_n$ you could then insert it like so  $$|X_{2n}-Z|\leq |X_{2n}-X_n|+|X_n-Z|$$ But then you should prove that $|X_{2n}-X_n|\xrightarrow{Pr}{0}$. This is true since "a sequence converges in Pr. to a limit if and only if it is Cauchy in Pr."

Comment: Don't pay much attention to the last sentence.